# Apply different styles to strings in a single TextArea in JavafX

Tags: string, fonts, textarea, javafx

Is there a way to style a substring of the text in a `TextArea`? `setStyle()` method is only available to the `TextArea` class.

Comment: With all your TextArea questions I figured I'd make sure you know about the strangely named [HTMLEditor](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/HTMLEditor.html)

Comment: Hi Brian, yep! I know of the HTML editor. but I am trying to develop a prototype for a text editor with a few special features that require me to build things from scratch (sort of). Would I be able to get the html text editor without the tool bar it comes with? The main goal is that I want to apply certain styles to sub strings in a text. I am just not sure yet what that text should be (Text Area does not seem to be the right one to use). I am trying java 1.8.. i'll report back... :/

Comment: Seems like TextFlow in Java 8 is what I am looking for. But it is not loading in Netbeans. Any ideas why? It is in the docs already, but in the installation. https://wikis.oracle.com/display/OpenJDK/Rich+Text+API+Samples

Comment: I guess it is not really it, because they are not editable...

Comment: melkhaldi - rather than posting lots of comments, you can edit your question and post your progress updates in the question (it's much easier to read and follow then).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using JDK 8, then this can be achieved by using [RichTextFX](https://github.com/TomasMikula/CodeAreaFX). It allows you to add style classes to text ranges.

Comment: I am currently using NetBean 7.4 with J7.45. If I upgrade, is it going to break things?

Comment: I cannot say about the upgrade question.

Comment: Ok I added installed 1.8, and applied to the project as the default library. 2 things: the previous text area still shows, but it is VERY blurry and fuzzy). The second thing is that even though java 8 is the default library for the project, when I add CodeArea area = new CodeArea, it does not offer to import. It only asks to create a CodeArea class. As per the example in the link above, the class type is CodeArea.

Comment: I added the "import codearea.control.CodeArea;" but it says it does not exist... my project browser shows only Java1.8 in Libraries.  This is strange

Comment: Looks like CodeAreaFX is not included in your project's classpath.

Comment: Ok I managed to add a JAR file which included it!. now it shows.. off I go to trying some magic :D i'll report back!