# Highlight text in JavaFx TextArea

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, textarea

I have a text area like below,

[image]

I need to highlight or select all the text "Highlight me". I don't find any methods to highlight the text in text area. Also I could not find any other API in JavaFX that highlights the occurrence of specific text or letter like JTextArea in Swing. Can any one suggest me on how to highlight String in the text area? Or is there any other API available apart from this text area in JavaFX?

My Code:

```
public class FXTextArea extends Application {

    /**
     * @param args
     *            the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage primaryStage) {
        Group root = new Group();

        final TextArea textArea = TextAreaBuilder.create().prefWidth(390)
                .wrapText(true).build();

        ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane();
        scrollPane.getStyleClass().add("noborder-scroll-pane");
        scrollPane.setContent(textArea);
        scrollPane.setFitToWidth(true);
        scrollPane.setPrefWidth(390);
        scrollPane.setPrefHeight(180);

        Button buttonLoad = new Button("Load");
        buttonLoad.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
                FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();

                // Set extension filter
                FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extFilter = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter(
                        "TXT files (*.txt)", "*.txt");
                fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().add(extFilter);

                // Show save file dialog
                File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(primaryStage);
                if (file != null) {
                    textArea.setText(readFile(file));
                }
                System.out.println(textArea.getText(0, 30));
                textArea.selectRange(0, 30);
            }

        });

        VBox vBox = VBoxBuilder.create().children(buttonLoad, scrollPane)
                .build();

        root.getChildren().add(vBox);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 400, 300));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private String readFile(File file) {
        StringBuilder stringBuffer = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;

        try {

            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

            String text;
            while ((text = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuffer.append(text);
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FXTextArea.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,
                    null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FXTextArea.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,
                    null, ex);
        } finally {
            try {
                bufferedReader.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(FXTextArea.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,
                        null, ex);
            }
        }

        return stringBuffer.toString();
    }
}
```

**Expected output:**

The lines should be highlight in any color as below. The "Highlight me" occurrence should be highlighted as below,

[image]

Comment: Give an example of you expected output ?

Comment: @Suzon added the screen shot of expected output. Hope this is fine :)

Answer (score 1):

You can take help from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20386132/apply-different-styles-to-strings-in-a-single-textarea-in-javafx/20386291#20386291). But the constraint is that you need to be on jdk8.

Comment: cann't this be used with Java 7 FX library? CodeFX is a third party jar. Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Yes, CodeFX is a third party jar. AFAIK, this cannot be used with Java 7.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your answer. I need to think twice on using CodeFx as i am currently using Java 7. +1 for possible solution.

Comment: If you want to not use CodeFX, then you would have to go the route of coding a custom textarea.

Comment: Yeah.. Thinking of that.. Thank you.