# change text colour dynamically in TextArea JavaFX

Tags: javafx-8, textarea, syntax-highlighting

In my project, I want to implement a syntax highlight feature. By this, my meaning is that when user types code in code-area then text will be highlighted immediately like IDE (Eclipse , Intellij, Netbeans).

For example if we type "import" in Intellij java IDE then it will color the word "import" with blue color. In my project, i want to implement the same thing.

My goal is to highlight specific keyword with blue color. For example, If keywords are  "mov" , "load" , "xor" , etc. then they should be colored with blue. My project is based on JavaFX.

I have used TextArea for Code-Editor. How can i highlight specific words in TextArea. Is TextArea a better for that or not? Is there any EditorPane like thing in JavaFX.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apply different styles to strings in a single TextArea in JavafX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20386132/apply-different-styles-to-strings-in-a-single-textarea-in-javafx)

Answer (score 1):

This is impossible with the JavaFX `TextArea` control; it does not contain the functionality to style ranges of text.

There are other options out there, however. I do not have any experience with it, but **[RichTextFX](https://github.com/FXMisc/RichTextFX)** seems to provide a basic framework for syntax highlighting, though much of the work would still be done by yourself.

There is also **[FxEditor](https://github.com/andy-goryachev/FxEditor)** but that is still in the very early stages.

Other than those, you could try a Google search for other options for a [javafx syntax highlighting textarea](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1GCEA_en&ei=-6YcW9PYI8nZzgLkj5P4BA&q=javafx%20syntax%20highlighting%20textarea&oq=javafx%20syntax%20highlighting%20textarea&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0.174573.174573.0.175172.1.1.0.0.0.0.165.165.0j1.1.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.1.164....0.-1ZEUdqvMEE) and see if you have better luck.

Otherwise, I'm afraid you would need to code your own from scratch.